# Cronjob metadata verification with using nodeName instead of nodeSelector

Tags: kubernetes

Given a template for the cronjob, is there a possible way to verify that the metadata that I configured is as intended? For example, in the following template I use only the cronjob name which is cronj, what is the purpose then of the job and pods metadata and when do they get used?

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: cronj
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      name: cron-job
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          name: cron-pod
```

Also when doing scheduling, what is the difference between using `nodeName: controlplane` and `nodeSelector: kubernetes.io/hostname: master`

Answer (score 3):

You can check out the documentation of cronjob in kuberenetes https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/. It states that a job creates one or more pods and that's why you need them. You can double check the container name in the pod description.

As for the difference between nodeName and nodeSelector, the main difference is that nodeName is a manual scheduler, while nodeSelector is scheduled using k8s scheduler. If you use nodeName then it will override the k8s scheduler.

Comment: And where can I see the other metadata that are created within the pods/jobs?

Comment: If you mean the timestamp for example,  it is generated just for you as a reference, you can get this resource as a yaml and you will find generated metadata within it